# Where do Safari or Chrome store the flash media data

Tags: safari, time-machine, adobe-flash

Where do Safari and Chrome store the flash media files? For example, I use Safari/Chrome to listen Pandora during work time, and all my work is done through ssh to other computers. However, in such scenario, my time machine still needs to backup several hundred MB data for every hour.

Btw, I've already exclude ~/Library/Caches directory from Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Poke around in the invisible folders /private/var/folders.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: In one of the folders therein--they are all named differently, per user--you will find the media files. Trash 'em. And of course, exclude the folder containing these files connected to your accountfrom future Time Machine, clone or backup.